# JavaScript how to convert Europe/Berlin timezone to local timezone date

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I have my note module which display notes made by user with date and time ,
using my API call i am receiving following date

`2020-02-08 10:58:00`
which is in Europe/Berlin timezone.

now on client side i want to display it in local time zone i.e in india it should be like

`2020-02-08 03:28:00`

i know moment js can do it but i dont know how to use it. so is there any way to do it? using either core javascript or momentjs?

following is what i have tried to get time string using moment js

```
moment(new Date(targetDateString)).fromNow();
```

but this always show me time five hours age as my local time zone is ITC and date is store in Europe/Berlin

Comment: Look at moment js timezone : https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

```js
var date = moment.tz("2020-02-08 10:58:00", "Europe/Berlin");
var localDate = moment.tz("2020-02-08 10:58:00", "Europe/Berlin").local();

console.log('Europe/Berlin', date.format());
console.log('Local', localDate.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i run your example both dates are same

Comment: tz is not a function in my version of moment js,it has something like zone,tz is deprecated

Comment: You have to setup [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) which is a seperate package.

Comment: moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js:595 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined any help?

Comment: moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js:484 Moment Timezone has no data for 2020-02-08 10:58:00. See

Comment: Can you please post a code example to help reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install moment-timezone from their website ('yarn add' or whatever) and replace your moment with the moment from moment-timezone.

Like this:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

Change timestamp from London To Berlin Time:
moment.tz(someTimeStamp, 'HHmmss','Europe/London').tz('Europe/Berlin').format('HH:mm:ss')

Change timestamp from UTC to browser's local time:
moment.tz(someTimeStamp, 'HHmmss','UTC').local().format('HH:mm:ss')
```